# How to remove list square brackets from serialized json string

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling a stored procedure using a controller.

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info] @call_id", 
                        new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id)).ToList();
jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(insert_query); // <-- using Newtonsoft.Json
```

The json string is the following:

```
"[{\"call_info_id\":18,\"call_id\":91389,\"user_id\":\"105bdbfb-d65a-42d3-ac79-c1e2575ed243\",\"call_arrive\":\"2020-04-03T21:51:24.797\",\"call_end\":\"2020-04-03T22:04:24.797\",\"info\":\"test\",\"AspNetUser\":null,\"Call\":null,\"StatusCode\":1}]"
```

Is there a way to remove the `[` and `]` brackets?

I want the json string to be:

```
{\"call_info_id\":18,\"call_id\":91389,\"user_id\":\"105bdbfb-d65a-42d3-ac79-c1e2575ed243\",\"call_arrive\":\"2020-04-03T21:51:24.797\",\"call_end\":\"2020-04-03T22:04:24.797\",\"info\":\"test\",\"AspNetUser\":null,\"Call\":null,\"StatusCode\":1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info] @call_id", 
                        new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id)).ToList();
if(insert_query!=null && insert_query.Count()>0)
{
jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(insert_query[0]);
}
```

This will serialise only 1st element so it wont have []

Comment: This will serialise only 1st element so it wont have []